# R: Layer-wise sum from several rasterstack

Tags: r, r-raster

I have several RasterBricks (one per year) with each brick containing 12 layers for each month with monthly precipitation sums. I want to calculate the average monthly precipitation for each month and pixel for all years. How can I calculate the mean of each 1st, 2nd,... layer using all bricks?

I have: mnthly.sum.1980, mnthly.sum1981, .... with

```
> mnthly.sum.1981
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 1100, 1200, 1320000, 12  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent     : 3500000, 4700000, 2100000, 3200000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=lcc +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +lat_1=35 +lat_2=65 +x_0=4000000 +y_0=2800000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : r_tmp_2023-03-23_125645_11340_84890.grd 
names      : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3, layer.4, layer.5, layer.6, layer.7, layer.8, layer.9, layer.10, layer.11, layer.12 
min values :       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,        0,        0,        0 
max values :   541.4,   358.4,   562.4,   384.0,   434.3,   384.0,   548.4,   396.8,   978.9,    568.9,    603.0,    638.2
```

I want to have a single RasterBrick with 12 layers of average monthly precipitation. Something like:

```
jan.avg <- mean(mnthly.sum.1980[[1]], mnthly.sum.1981[[1]], ...)
feb.avg <- mean(mnthly.sum.1980[[2]], mnthly.sum.1981[[2]], ...)
```

...
and so on!

Thanks for your help
Thomas

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

a possible approach, using the rasters' values only:

```
library(raster)
set.seed(4711)

## helper function to create example bricks 
## with three monthly layers of 2 x 2 cells (and random values between 800 and 900):

get_brick = function(layer_names){
  setNames(
  layer_names |>
    Map(f = \(x) raster(matrix(sample(800:900, 4), 2, 2))) |>
    Reduce(f = \(x, y) addLayer(x, y)),
  layer_names
  )
}
```

create two sample bricks:

```
brick_1 <- get_brick(c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'))
brick_2 <- get_brick(c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'))
```

```
> brick_1
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 2, 2, 4, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
names      : Jan, Feb, Mar 
min values : 806, 822, 801 
max values : 868, 859, 888
```

`Reduce` the list of bricks to month-wise sums, and divide them by brick count to obtain the average:

```
bricks <- list(brick_1, brick_2)

(bricks |> Reduce(f = \(x, y) x + y)) / length(bricks)
```

```
## > (bricks |>  Reduce(f = \(x, y) x + y)) / length(bricks)
## class      : RasterBrick 
## dimensions : 2, 2, 4, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
## resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
## extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
## crs        : NA 
## source     : memory
## names      :   Jan,   Feb,   Mar 
## min values : 808.0, 812.5, 844.5 
## max values : 864.5, 847.5, 883.5
```